Как создать новый столбец в датафрейме, основываясь на поиске подстроки в другом столбце?
У меня есть столбец с описанием деятельности компании. Описание состоит из нескольких слов. Я подготовил список с ключевыми словами и хочу присваивать в новый столбец 1, если в описании деятельности встречается слово из списка с ключевыми словами, в противном случае 0. Как мне это реализовать?
Что имею:
medical_list = ['medical', 'health', 'vitamins']




id компании
Описание




1
"medical tools, sport inventory"


2
"it management, analytics"


3
"sport and health"



Что хочу получить:



id компании
Описание
is_medical




1
"medical tools, sport inventory"
1


2
"it management, analytics"
0


3
"sport and health"
1




так что именно вы не знаете, о чём именно спрашиваете? как добавить столбец? как проверить, входит ли одна строка в другую? уточните это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Недавно был похожий вопрос. Вы пробовали искать среди ответов? решение - в использовании метода contains:
df:
   id                            desc
0   1  medical tools, sport inventory
1   2        it management, analytics
2   3                sport and health

df["is_medical"] = df["desc"].str.contains("|".join(medical_list)).astype(int)

теперь df:
   id                            desc  is_medical
0   1  medical tools, sport inventory           1
1   2        it management, analytics           0
2   3                sport and health           1


